Keyboard buffer management
On Linux, when a shell is running a process it usually allows you to keep typing commands which will be processed when the process finishes. The same can be observed in other applications that behave like a "shell". For example, say we do this in ipython:
import time

time.sleep(4)

While "sleeping", we can still use the keyboard and anything put on the buffer will be delivered to the input of ipython upon returning from the sleep function.
However, while some processes are working, the keyboard is completely blocked. It is not only that the characters are not echoed on the terminal but they are not even available on the prompt when the process returns.
What is this difference due to? Is this something to do with the process itself? How can I replicate this characteristic? That is, what do I need to have in place in my programs so that when they run, the keyboard buffer is completely ignored?


While "sleeping", we can still use the keyboard and anything put on the buffer will be delivered to the input of ipython upon returning from the sleep function.

That's not really a feature of the program, though – the input stream stdin doesn't randomly lose data just because a program doesn't instantly read all its contents :) Ipython as counterexample to a shell is maybe not the best example, as it is a shell…

However, while some processes are working, the keyboard is completely blocked. It is not only that the characters are not echoed on the terminal but they are not even available on the prompt when the process returns.

That's because that process opened the stdin file descriptor as passed on from the shell and read stuff from. That means that things aren't available afterwards.

That is, what do I need to have in place in my programs so that when they run, the keyboard buffer is completely ignored?

Ignored by whom? By the program itself? Simply don't read stdin.
By the shell? Strictly speaking, the shell doesn't "ignore" it, it simply never gets it, when your program consumes it. read() everything from stdin that there is, before you exit your program.
To avoid blocking in read when you've got no input, a portable way would be to do a select (with zero timeout) on stdin, and only read as many bytes as are available (in a loop, until select returns none).

Hi Marcus, thanks for your response. It was not a counterexample, ipython is divided into the REPL and the process that runs the actual python code. But, anyway to understand what I am talking about try to do (for example) sudo apt-get upgrade and while that is working try to type anything. Characters are not echoed to the terminal and anything typed is "gone" after the upgrade returns. If you were to do a long grep, you can type while grep is working and anything typed will be picked up once the grep process returns.

ah so you don't want to modify some software (that's how I interpreted your question "what do I need to have in place in my programs"!) but want to call it such that any "leftover" keypresses done during them don't end up in the shell; do I get that correctly?

Yes, I want to understand how this works so that I can replicate it in my programs.

Well, if you want to get that behaviour: my answer tells you how :)
